# How can I map then update rows of values?

Tags: sql, sqlite

There is a table which stores a file's location on my disk. All files are in one folder and I will move them to another folder. After moving the files I should update all database records.

Can I do it with one SQL query (applying a mapping function to all values in the `fileLocation` column) instead of selecting each value to update separately?

Answer (score 0):

If you moved everything from oldFolder to newFolder, you can use the `REPLACE()` function to update this in the table.

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET fileLocation = REPLACE(fileLocation, 'oldFolder', 'newFolder');
```